# How do I start and stop the on board wireless access point?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, wireless, pi-3b+, access-point

I would like to have my wireless access point available at particular periods of the day and not at others. I have a RPi3+ running default Raspbian and followed https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md to get the access point up and running using the onboard wifi. What is the best command line to switch the access point on and off properly?  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are using **Raspbian** and you have setup the access point with **hostapd**. To switch the access point this commands should do:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl stop hostapd.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl start hostapd.service
```

It is difficult to say much more about start/stop `hostapd` because I don't know anything about your setup. Do you use a stand alone access point, or with a wired uplink (**eth0**), or with a wireless uplink (**wlan0**) together with `wpa_supplicant`? If you use a setup with **systemd-networkd** then you have clean control over the services with start/stop. To get an idea what I mean you may have a look at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866) and [Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866). The last one has a tested table what happens with start/stop the services.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I am using hostapd however when I tried the stop command above and waited for a few minutes for it to disappear from visible networks the access point was still available to our various devices.  Is the network supposed to disappear when the stop command is run?

Comment: @s.k I have updated the answer. If everything works as expected then the access point should disappear.

Comment: To clarify I have an RPi3+ running default Raspberian and followed https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md to get the access point up and running using the onboard wifi.  I will read the references that you provided and try again.